# How to create data frame from list in pyspark without using for loop?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have list like below:

```python
rrr=[[(1,(3,1)),(2, (3,2)),(3, (3, 2)),(1,(4,1)),(2, (4,2))]]

df_input = []
```

and next I defined header like below:

```python
df_header=['sid', 'tid', 'srank']
```

Using for loop appending the data into the empty list:

```python
for i in rrr:
     for j in i:
            df_input.append((j[0], j[1][0], j[1][1]))
df_input

Output : [(1, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 3, 2)]
```

Create Data Frame like below:

```python
   df = spark.createDataFrame(df_input, df_header)
    df.show()

+---+---+------+
| sid|tid|srank|
+---+---+------+
|  1|  3|     1|
|  2|  3|     2|
|  3|  3|     2|
+---+---+------+
```

Now my question is how to Create Data Frame without using any external for loop(like above). Input list contains more then 1 Lack records.

Comment: Read it from a CSV, a JDBC source, a Hive table, a parquet/avro file on HDFS.

Comment: if the problem is the for loop see the list comprehensions...

Comment: List comprehension may not work. I have a large dataset, so I don't want to use list for solving this

Comment: What is "1 Lack records"???

Comment: My original LIst Contain more then one lack objects i.e.indirectly i am telling what ever list object i add that is just for sample.

Comment: Still unclear (what is a lack object?), but anyway, since my answer arguably does exactly what you requested, kindly accept it - thanks

Comment: Hi desertnaut  ,thanks for quick response if my data set is like " rrr=[[(1,(3,1)),(2, (3,2)),(3, (3, 2)),(1,(4,1)),(2, (4,2))]]" ,it is failing to display last two records  i.e.(1,(4,1)),(2, (4,2)).

Comment: it certainly does not fail - all works as expected! See updated answer

Comment: Can you please accept the answer, since it does *exactly* what you asked for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you realize that your initial list is a *nested* one. i.e. an actual list as a unique element of an outer one, then you'll see that the solution comes easily by taking only its first (and only) element into consideration:

```python
spark.version
#  u'2.1.1'

from pyspark.sql import Row

# your exact data:
rrr=[[(1,(3,1)),(2, (3,2)),(3, (3, 2)),(1,(4,1)),(2, (4,2))]]
df_header=['sid', 'tid', 'srank']

df = sc.parallelize(rrr[0]).map(lambda x: Row(x[0], x[1][0],x[1][1])).toDF(schema=df_header)
df.show()
# +---+---+-----+ 
# |sid|tid|srank|
# +---+---+-----+
# |  1|  3|    1|
# |  2|  3|    2|
# |  3|  3|    2|
# |  1|  4|    1| 
# |  2|  4|    2|
# +---+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution one: to introduce toDF() transformation (but with input modified)*

```
from pyspark.sql import Row    
ar=[[1,(3,1)],[2, (3,2)],[3, (3,2)]]
sc.parallelize(ar).map(lambda x: Row(sid=x[0], tid=x[1][0],srank=x[1][1])).toDF().show()

+---+-----+---+
|sid|srank|tid|
+---+-----+---+
|  1|    1|  3|
|  2|    2|  3|
|  3|    2|  3|
+---+-----+---+
```

*Solution 2: with the requested input matrix use list comprehension, numpy flatten and reshape*

```
import numpy as np 
x=[[(1,(3,1)),(2, (3,2)),(3, (3, 2))]]
ar=[[(j[0],j[1][0],j[1][1]) for j in i] for i in x]
flat=np.array(ar).flatten()
flat=flat.reshape(len(flat)/3, 3)
sc.parallelize(flat).map(lambda x: Row(sid=int(x[0]),tid=int(x[1]),srank=int(x[2]))).toDF().show()

+---+-----+---+
|sid|srank|tid|
+---+-----+---+
|  1|    1|  3|
|  2|    2|  3|
|  3|    2|  3|
+---+-----+---+

#works also with N,M matrix
number_columns=3
x=[[(1,(3,1)),(2, (3,2)),(3, (3, 2))],[(5,(6,7)),(8, (9,10)),(11, (12, 13))]]
ar=[[(j[0],j[1][0],j[1][1]) for j in i] for i in x]
flat=np.array(ar).flatten()
flat=flat.reshape(int(len(flat)/number_columns), number_columns)
sc.parallelize(flat).map(lambda x: Row(sid=int(x[0]),tid=int(x[1]),srank=int(x[2]))).toDF().show()
+---+-----+---+
|sid|srank|tid|
+---+-----+---+
|  1|    1|  3|
|  2|    2|  3|
|  3|    2|  3|
|  5|    7|  6|
|  8|   10|  9|
| 11|   13| 12|
+---+-----+---+
```

Comment: please check the data format," rrr=[[(1,(3,1)),(2, (3,2)),(3, (3, 2))]]" not like ar=[[1,(3,1)],[2, (3,2)],[3, (3,2)]]

Comment: @saikumar in the second example I held it. But I have forgotten the declaration of it.I update immediately

Comment: i am getting error after executing  ">>> flat=flat.reshape(len(flat)/3, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: substitute `int(len(flat)/3)` to delete the error... but if the structure changes and the flat array is not perfectly divisible by 3 this won't work properly. The main assumption is that the structure of input won't change.

Comment: @saikumar (& respondent, actually): why bother with numpy arrays, `flatten`, `reshape`, conversion to integers etc? Doesn't the first, clean solution work??

Comment: @desertnaut in the first solution the original input was modified

Comment: I modified the answer but not removed it. in the first case the code is useful if you have a matrix well formatted. Could be a more generic case